# Looping SQL query - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get a query to loop through a set of pre-defined integers:

**I've made the query very simple for this question.. This is pseudo code as well obviously!**

```
my_id = 0
WHILE my_id < 10
  SELECT * from table where id = :my_id`
  my_id += 1
END
```

I know that for this query I could just do something like where id < 10.. But the actual query I'm performing is about 60 lines long, with quite a few window statements all referring to the variable in question.

It works, and gets me the results I want when I have the variable set to a single figure.. I just need to be able to re-run the query 10 times with different variables hopefully ending up with one single set of results.

So far I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stay_prices ( a_product_id int ) RETURNS TABLE (
    pid int,
    pp_price int
) AS $$
DECLARE
  nights int;
  nights_arr INT[] := ARRAY[1,2,3,4];
  j int;
BEGIN
  j := 1;
  FOREACH nights IN ARRAY nights_arr LOOP

    -- query here..

  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I'm getting this back:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

So do I need to get my query to `SELECT ... INTO` the returning table somehow? Or is there something else I can do?

EDIT: this is an example of the actual query I'm running:

```
\x auto
\set nights 7

WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        product_id, night,
        LAG(night, (:nights - 1)) OVER (
            PARTITION BY product_id
            ORDER BY night
        ) AS night_start,
        SUM(price_pp_gbp) OVER (
            PARTITION BY product_id
            ORDER BY night
            ROWS BETWEEN (:nights - 1) PRECEDING
            AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS pp_price,
        MIN(spaces_available) OVER (
            PARTITION BY product_id
            ORDER BY night
            ROWS BETWEEN (:nights - 1) PRECEDING
            AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS min_spaces_available,
        MIN(period_date_from) OVER (
            PARTITION BY product_id
            ORDER BY night
            ROWS BETWEEN (:nights - 1) PRECEDING
            AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS min_period_date_from,
        MAX(period_date_to) OVER (
            PARTITION BY product_id
            ORDER BY night
            ROWS BETWEEN (:nights - 1) PRECEDING
            AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS max_period_date_to

    FROM products_nightlypriceperiod pnpp
    WHERE
        spaces_available >= 1
        AND min_group_size <= 1
        AND night >= '2016-01-01'::date
        AND night <= '2017-01-01'::date
)
SELECT
    product_id as pid,
    CASE WHEN x.pp_price > 0 THEN x.pp_price::int ELSE null END as pp_price,
    night_start as from_date,
    night as to_date,
    (night-night_start)+1 as duration,
    min_spaces_available as spaces
FROM x
WHERE
    night_start = night - (:nights - 1)
    AND min_period_date_from = night_start
    AND max_period_date_to = night;
```

That will get me all the `nights` night periods available for all my products in 2016 along with the price for the period and the max number of spaces I could fill in that period.

I'd like to be able to run this query to get all the periods available between 2 and 30 days for all my products.

This is likely to produce a table with millions of rows. The plan is to re-create this table periodically to enable a very quick look up of what's available for a particular date. The `products_nightlypriceperiod` represents a night of availability of a product - e.g. `Product X has 3 spaces left for Jan 1st 2016, and costs £100 for the night`.

Comment: Put the list of numbers in a (temp) table and you won't need a loop.

Comment: Or use a CTE with the desired numbers: `with the_values (my_id) as ( values (1),(2),(3))...` and the join against that. Or if the numbers are always sequential, use `generate_series()`

Answer (score 2):

Why use a loop?  You can do something like this (using your first query):

```
with params as (
      select generate_series(1, 10) as id
     )
select t.*
from params cross join
     table t
where t.id = params.id;
```

You can modify `params` to have the values you really want.  Then just use `cross join` and let the database "do the looping."

Comment: not seen that.. Thanks. will take a look into it - the sql statement I have does has a sub-query in it - and both the subquery and main query use the same variable. I will put an edited version into the question as that will complicate things.

Comment: @GuyBowden . . . Put `params` in the subquery and then propagate the value outwards.

Comment: that's fine until you need to use the param inside a LAG or ROW statement.. I will edit my question with an example query.